# Applying a date filter for each parent containing start and enddate using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform the following xml in such a way that:

1. the current input is copied for every unique startdate in the xml (and are grouped by this startdate)
2. each created CompoundEmployee structure only contains those parent nodes for which the startdate of the group is within the its child startdate-enddate range.

Input:

```xml
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <CompoundEmployee>
        <employment_information>
            <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
            <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
            <job_information>
                <start_date>2021-12-01</start_date>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
            </job_information>
            <job_information>
                <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-11-30</end_date>
            </job_information>
        </employment_information>
        <employment_information>
            <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
            <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
            <job_information>
                <start_date>2021-05-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
            </job_information>
            <job_information>
                <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-04-30</end_date>
            </job_information>
        </employment_information>
    </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="//CompoundEmployee">
        <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="." group-by="//start_date">
                <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <start_date date="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <CompoundEmployee>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="./*[start_date &lt;= current-grouping-key() and end_date &gt; current-grouping-key()]"/>
                        </CompoundEmployee>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </start_date>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current output that's being generated is close to what I want: each group contains only one employment information node where the startdate of the group is within the start-enddate range of the employment information. However, the same does not happen for the job_information nodes within employment_information:

```xml
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <start_date date="2021-03-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-05-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-04-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-05-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-05-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-04-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-11-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-12-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-11-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-12-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-12-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-11-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

How do I need to change my XSLT so that each employment_information node contains only the one job_information node where the group startdate is within its start-enddate range? It's possible for the XML to contain deeper levels of nesting and differently named nodes (each containing a start and enddate), so I'd like to avoid explicit references to "employment_information" and "job_information".

Expected output:

```xml
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
    <start_date date="2021-03-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-04-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-05-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-03-01</start_date>
                <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-05-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-10-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-11-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>2021-11-30</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
    <start_date date="2021-12-01">
        <CompoundEmployee>
            <employment_information>
                <start_date>2021-11-01</start_date>
                <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                <job_information>
                    <start_date>2021-12-01</start_date>
                    <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
                </job_information>
            </employment_information>
        </CompoundEmployee>
    </start_date>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```